# Is it possible to reduce the summation/product?

Tags: summation, products

Specifically, is it possible to combine the products? Both summation/products carry the same bounds.

$$\sum_{n=2}^{x}\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}f(x,n,j)+\sum_{n=2}^{x}\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}f(x+2,n,j)$$

This is as far as I got:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{x}\left(\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}f(x,n,j)+\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}f(x+2,n,j)\right)$$

Comment: No, I don't think so. Without knowing more about $f$, we can't predict how $f(x,n,j)$ and $f(x+2,n,j)$ are related to each other. If we DID have info about $f$ I would try and look for a way to factor shared terms out from both products.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in a comment, there's no further simplification beyond what you've already done without more knowledge about $f$.